# How to get content in webBrowser control

Tags: wpf

Assume I type uri in a textbox and click a button load, a web page is loaded into my webbrowswer control, then I highlight a piece of text in the webbroswer control. And now, how  can I get hightlighted text and display in another textbox? (no copy/paste)

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you want to use copy/paste? The MSDN says: "The WebBrowser control internally instantiates the native WebBrowser ActiveX control.", so accessing the selected text in the control will be no easy task without copy/paste.

Answer (score 3):

[Retrieving Selected Text from Webbrowser control in .net(C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217353/retrieving-selected-text-from-webbrowser-control-in-netc)

```
    IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;

    IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection= htmlDocument.selection;

    if (currentSelection!=null) 
    {
        IHTMLTxtRange range= currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;

        if (range != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(range.text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is for winforms, not for WPF. WPF's WebBrowser.Document doesn't have a DomDocument property.