# Fetch the data from web browser page to a wpf application

Tags: c#, http, browser

I have a wpf application in that i have one text box in which i enter the url and i am fetching that web page in web browser control.Think general for example if i am opening any web page in web browser control in a wpf application i want fetch all the text from that web browser control and diplay it in a text box. from that text box i can export it into any file. i now need information on how to fetch all data from web browser control and then put it into a multi line text box.

Comment: Why not just use wdsl.exe?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx

Comment: No No.ok lets make this as general if i want to fetch any other web page data how to do that. i used web browser control . to open the web page but i am not able fetch the data from that control.

Comment: Where does "I need to fetch the data from that web service url which is shown on the browser and create a .wsdl file" fit in.

Comment: IHTMLDocument2 htmlDocument = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;                                 IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection= htmlDocument.selection;    if (currentSelection!=null) {                           IHTMLTxtRange range= currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;                                                    if (range != null) { MessageBox.Show(range.text); } }              i found this the problem is without selecting the data is not fetched . i dont want to select any thing i just want to fetch the data on its own

Comment: i actually want to fetch the data which is shown on web service url so i told that. please help me in doing that. i found a link         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099792/how-to-get-content-in-webbrowser-control?answertab=oldest#tab-top but it is not so help full so i am asking a question

Comment: Hi blam  you talked about wsdl.exe can you please provide info on it

Comment: i want have an application which uses wsdl.exe to create wsdl files at run time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse objects from System.Net to communicate with a webserver.

e.g.

```
string GetWebPage(string address)
{
    string responseText;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(address);

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
        {
            responseText = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    return responseText;
}
```

You can then set the text of your textbox using:

```
myTextBox.Text = GetWebPage(address);
```

To make things nicer for your users, you should make the web requests asynchronous, so you don't lock up the UI while the data is downloading. You could use a `BackgroundWorkerThread` to do this.

Comment: This is the error message i am getting The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Comment: The 401 error is because the website requires authentication - e.g. a username and password. If you visit the website in a normal browser does it prompt you to login?