# Web Browser selection to variable

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a windows application with a web browser. How do i putt a text selection in the web browser into a variable within my Windows application.

Comment: Read the documentation of the browser control you use. It probably has a Text or Html property that you can set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out - it has what you need:

[Retrieving Selected Text from Webbrowser control in .net(C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217353/retrieving-selected-text-from-webbrowser-control-in-netc)