# How to get selected text in webpage

Tags: windows-phone-8, browser, selection

I'm going to select some text in a webpage using webbrowser and get the text to deal with. Could you give some clue?

I have tried injecting the JavaScript as below and invoke this script, but it does not work.

```
window.clipboardData.setData("Text", document.selection.createRange().toString())
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217353/retrieving-selected-text-from-webbrowser-control-in-netc

Comment: hi, this is a wp8 app, so it is different from winform webbrowser.